# Magento 2 Rest api to create a order

Tags: rest, magento2, php-7

> I need to use the Magento REST API to create an order.Which API(s)
>   should I use to achieve this Or what steps to be follwed to create an
>   order with complete billing,shipping,payment details?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use salesOrderRepositoryV1 API /V1/orders/create

source : http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/